# Why does placement new create/add object correctly 1st time but doesn't the 2nd time?

Tags: c++, arrays, debugging, arraylist

I have the following simplified code for creating a generic arraylist in C++:

```
template <typename T>
class ArrayList
{
public:
    ArrayList(int size = 100);
    void add(T item);
private:
    T* arr;
    size_t allocatedSize;
    size_t actualSize;
};

template <typename T>
ArrayList<T>::ArrayList(int size)
    :arr(static_cast<T*>(::operator new(sizeof(T)*size)))
    , actualSize(0)
    , allocatedSize(size)
{

}

template <typename T>
void ArrayList<T>::add(T item)
{
    if (actualSize >= allocatedSize)
        resize();

    new(arr + actualSize) T(std::move(item));
    actualSize++;
}
```

and I have the following test code:

```
int main()
{
    ArrayList<int> testArray = ArrayList<int>();

    testArray.add(5);
    testArray.add(7);
}
```

The problem is that 5 is added to `arr` correctly, but 7 is not. Here is the what the debugger looks like for each situation.

For `testArray.add(5)`:

This is what the variables looks like right **before** 5 is added to `arr`
[image: Before 5 is added]

This is what the variables looks like right **after** 5 is added to `arr`
[image: After 5 is added]

For `testArray.add(7)`:

This is what the variables looks like right **before** 7 is added to `arr`
[image: Before 7 is added]

This is what the variables looks like right **after** 7 is added to `arr`
[image: After 7 is added]

Notice how when `5` is added to `arr` at memory address `0x00dfec58`, it is added correctly. But when `7` is added to arr the 2nd time around, `7` is not added to `arr` at all. I'd like to know how to solve this problem.

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: @VeniVidiVici that looks like VS 2013 or VS 2015.

Comment: VS 2015 for this question

Comment: What happens if you type 
(int*)0x00dfec5c
i believe it should return 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The debugger does not know that `arr` pointing to an array. It is just an `int*`. And the value of the `int` at the address it is pointing to is the first one you added, 5, which is what it's showing you. It has no idea what the relation is between `actualSize` and `arr`. So, the 7 is there, it's just that the debugger is not showing it, because it doesn't know that you want it to.

Check the value of `arr[1]`, and you should see your 7.